# Trying to create a carousel effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are four characters of which only one is being shown when the page is loaded. 
There are two arrows. One on the left and one on the right. 
When clicked on left arrow, the character present will fadeout and the previous character is faded in. When clicked on right arrow, the character present will fadeout and the next character is faded in. 
I've figure out how to fadeOut the present character in the screen, but don't know how to fadeIn the next or previous character when clicked on the arrows.

Here is the fiddle which I created to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9K7bf/32/

And here is the code:

The HTML:

```
<section id="characters">
    <div id="one" class="character"></div>
    <div id="two" class="character"></div>
    <div id="three" class="character"></div>
    <div id="four" class="character"></div>
</section>

<div id="arrow-left"></div>
<div id="arrow-right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#characters{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#one{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
#two{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: none;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
#three{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: none;
    background-color: purple;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
#four{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
#arrow-left{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
}
#arrow-right{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#arrow-right").on('click', function(){
    $(".character").fadeOut().this();
  });  
    $("#arrow-left").on('click', function(){
    $(".character").fadeOut().this();
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the fiddle and for the general willingness to learn

Comment: Are you looking for something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/9K7bf/63/)? If it is, I will explain what is done in the answer. And +1 for the same reason the amenthes has said.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I don't want to throw my question out there for a quick answer.
This platform is intended to record questions and answers so that others can learn from it as well. 
And I this is my way of attributing to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the effect by doing the below. Effectively we have to find out what is the current item using a counter and then keep traversing through it.

As an additional point, you can also avoid repetitions in the arrow boxes by assigning it a `class='arrow'` and providing all common properties under it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0; // Counter variable to keep track of the current item
  $("#arrow-right").on('click', function() {
    $(".character").eq(i).fadeOut('fast'); // Quickly fade out the current element
    i = i < 3 ? i + 1 : 0; // Increment counter till it reaches 3 (because element index is from 0 to 3). If it reaches 3 then we reset to 0 to loop back again.
    $(".character").eq(i).fadeIn('slow'); // Slowly fade in the next element. Note i here is the next element because we have already incremented the counter.
  });
  $("#arrow-left").on('click', function() {
    $(".character").eq(i).fadeOut('fast');
    i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : 3; // Same as for the right click except here the logic is reverse as we have to go back.
    $(".character").eq(i).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#characters {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative; /* Need because the characters would be absolutely positioned relative to their parent box */
}
.character { /* Created this class to put in all common properties to avoid repetition */
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute; /* This is required because all elements have to be positioned one on top of another */
  left: 50%; /* Required for positioning the boxes */
  top: 50%;  /* Required for positioning the boxes */
}
#one {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
}
#two {
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
#three {
  display: none;
  background-color: purple;
}
#four {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
}
.arrow { /* Common class for common properties */
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}
#arrow-left {
  float: left;
}
#arrow-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="characters">
  <div id="one" class="character"></div>
  <div id="two" class="character"></div>
  <div id="three" class="character"></div>
  <div id="four" class="character"></div>
</section>
<div id="arrow-left" class='arrow'></div> <!-- Note the addition of class -->
<div id="arrow-right" class='arrow'></div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9K7bf/75/)

Comment: Working great exactly as I wanted.
And thank you very much for the explanation behind the code. That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

I made a newer version of your jsfiddle. One thing, i added, was a counter, indicating what's currently active (see `activeItem` in the following code).

This is intended to show you a new direction, not to code everythign for you. Things you might want to solve next are:

- there's a lot of duplication, this could be way more elegant.
- It does not detect wrap-around (smaller than zero, larger then three (remember: javascript counts from zero))
- you couldn't re-use this mutliple times across the page with all the IDs.
- fade-in items will jump around, because they are `display:block` (CSS term). That means, as long as they are visible, they are reserving their place on the page and displace other things. This could be fixed with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` in CSS, depending on your surrounding code.

Here it goes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // store what's current
    var activeItem = 0;

    $("#arrow-right").on('click', function(){
        $(".character").eq(activeItem).fadeOut();
        activeItem++;
        $(".character").eq(activeItem).fadeIn();
    });  

    $("#arrow-left").on('click', function(){
        $(".character").eq(activeItem).fadeOut();
        activeItem--;
        $(".character").eq(activeItem).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

[newer version the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9K7bf/62/)

Comment: -Completely agree with that the code could be more elegant. 
-I very much like the example that @Harry made. It is a loop, which your is not. 
-Thank you for the CSS explanation. Good to know that small detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use .next() and .prev().
Note: this only works if you don't want clicking next on the last one to return to the beggining.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#arrow-right").on('click', function(){
    var next = $(".character:visible").next().attr("id");
    $(".character").fadeOut();
    $("#"+next).fadeIn();
});  
$("#arrow-left").on('click', function(){
    var prev = $(".character:visible").prev().attr("id");
    $(".character").fadeOut();
    $("#"+prev).fadeIn();
});
});
```

EDIT:Clicking next on the last button broke it so I added if statement. You could use else to change the css of the button if it is the last.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#arrow-right").on('click', function(){
        var next = $(".character:visible").next().attr("id");
        if(next){
            $(".character").fadeOut();
            $("#"+next).fadeIn();
        }
    });  
    $("#arrow-left").on('click', function(){
        var prev = $(".character:visible").prev().attr("id");
        if(prev){
            $(".character").fadeOut();
           $("#"+prev).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: +1. As Brain had mentioned in amenthes' answer, he is looking for a loop. But nevertheless this is a good alternate option if looping is not required.

Comment: Missed the loop part. I have a tendency to not read the whole thing. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, you could implement looping. If ou changed it to:    if(!next){next=1;} that would bring you back to the first one.

Comment: Very true, I created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9K7bf/117/) for that also. You can maybe add that to your answer if you wish to :)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is doing exactly what you asked it to. You click the arrow and the character fades out. Nowhere in the script have you assigned any variables to define the other characters. You just reference them in the css.

With the number of free jquery sliders out there why not just use a plugin like Nivo? Or google "How to build a jquery slider from scratch". There a number of tutorials out there.

Comment: Good point! 
However I'm trying to code it myself and not use a plugin, so that I may improve my coding skills. 
I am aware of the fadeOut code working correct. 
I hope I can get some help with the fadeIn part as I had described in the question :)

Comment: That is why I suggested a tutorial, the javascript is much more complex than just a fade in. You have to define the characters as variables.

Comment: Defining the characters as variables is the part that made me think about it differently. I actually thought the answer would have something to do with .hasClass(), but @Harry explained it detailed and well. 
I am practising JS continuously, but this was just beyond my level at this stage.